# Parse multiple doubles from string in C#

Tags: c#, text, parsing

I have a string that contains a known number of double values.  What's the cleanest way (via C#) to parse the string and plug the results into matching scalar variables.  Basically, I want to do the equivalent of this `sscanf` statement, but in C#:

```
sscanf( textBuff, "%lg %lg %lg %lg %lg %lg", &X, &Y, &Z, &I, &J, &K );
```

... assuming that "`textBuff`" might contain the following:

```
"-1.123    4.234  34.12  126.4  99      22"
```

... and that the number of space characters between each value might vary.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
string textBuff = "-1.123    4.234  34.12  126.4  99      22";

double[] result = textBuff
    .Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => double.Parse(s))
    .ToArray();

double x = result[0];
//    ...
double k = result[5];
```

or

```
string textBuff = "-1.123    4.234  34.12  126.4  99      22";

string[] result = textBuff
    .Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

double x = double.Parse(result[0]);
//    ...
double k = double.Parse(result[5]);
```

Comment: Think you need a lambda for that select.
Select(x => double.Parse(x)) should work.

Comment: @Ty - the code shown will work.  The lamba is exchangeable for the method group itself.

Comment: @Drew: Ty is right. "The type arguments for method ...Select... cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly." I've fixed that.

Comment: The first option really cut a lot out of my own code just now. Thanks dtb. And Ty is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 4):

You can use String.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) to split it into "single values". Then it's a straight Double.Parse (or TryParse)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( Match m in Regex.Matches(inputString, @"[-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?") )
    DoSomething(m.Value);
```

Comment: The answer to the question is moved to DoSomething(), and it won't accept 1E6 etc.