# C# - Parsing a line of text - what's the best way to do this?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse multiple doubles from string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406129/parse-multiple-doubles-from-string-in-c)

Say I have a line of text that looks as follows:

"45.690            24.1023        .09223  4.1334"

What would be the most efficient way, in C#, to extract just the numbers from this line? The number of spaces between each number varies and is unpredictable from line to line. I have to do this thousands of times, so efficiency is key.

Thanks.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406129

Comment: What is your desired extract? 456902410230922341334?

Comment: You might find some useful material here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561273/parse-an-integer-from-a-string-with-trailing-garbage, though those solutions are for integers only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<double> doubles = s.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                               .Select<string, double>(double.Parse)
```

Updated to use StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries since the number of spaces varies

Comment: @dtb thanks for your ghost comment, was fixing as you posted

Comment: This works if you change it to: s.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(double.Parse);

Close enough for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Use a Regex split. This will allow you to split on any whitespace of any length between your numbers:

```
string input = "45.690 24.1023 .09223 4.1334";
string pattern = "\\s*";            // Split on whitepsace

string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
foreach (string match in substrings)
{
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
}
```

Comment: throw an ampersand in there and you get +1

Comment: Wouldn't the pattern be `"\\s+"`?

Comment: Why yes. Yes it would be. Sorry, zipping between VB and C# my fingers get confused.

Comment: @Sky: Where would I put this ampersand?

Comment: umm, before the quote that you just put the escape after... 6 one, 1/2 dozen other. +1

Answer (score 0):

I haven't measured, but simplicity is key if you are trying to be efficient so probably something like

```
var chars = new List<char>();
for( int i =0; i < numChars; ++i )
    if( char.IsDigit( text[i] ) )
        chars.Add(text[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want efficient.....

```
var regex = new Regex(@"([\d\.]+)",  RegexOptions.Compiled)
var matches = regex.Matches(input);
```